Cannot add image using Java Spring Boot and thymeleaf
I made a talent manager using spring and thymeleaf and had no issues being able to add a multipart file(image). I am currently making an ecommerce practice website and i feel like ive tried everything, including making it almost an exact replica of the talent manager and i cannot get the image to upload. Everything included is a condensed version only including code relating to the image file.
    ProductDao {
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "main_image", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] mainImage;
    private String mainImageFileName;
    private String base64Image;
    }

    ProductDto {

    private byte[] mainImage;
    private String mainImageFileName;
    private String base64Image;

    public ProductDto(byte[] mainImage,
                      String mainImageFileName,
                      String base64Image) {

        this.mainImage = mainImage;
        this.mainImageFileName = mainImageFileName;
        this.base64Image = base64Image;

    }

    public ProductDto() {
    }
}

    @Service
    public interface ProductService {
    Product save(ProductDto productDto);
    }

    @Service
    public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final ProductDao productDao;

    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductDao productDao) {
        this.productDao = productDao;}

    public Product save(ProductDto productDto) {
        Product product = new Product(
                productDto.getMainImage(), productDto.getMainImageFileName(),
                productDto.getBase64Image());
        return productDao.save(product);
    }
}

    @Controller
    public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;
    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }
    @PostMapping("/addProduct") //an exact replica of the method that worked in the talent manager
    public String addItem(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductDto productDto, 
    @RequestParam("mainImage") MultipartFile mainImage) {
        if (!mainImage.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] imageBytes = mainImage.getBytes();
                productDto.setMainImage(imageBytes);
                productDto.setMainImageFileName(mainImage.getOriginalFilename());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        productService.save(productDto);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model, Principal principal) {
    UserDetails userDetails = 
    userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());
    model.addAttribute("userdetail", userDetails);

    List<Product> productList = productService.findAll();
    productList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Product::getProductId));
    model.addAttribute("productList", productList);

    for (Product product : productList) {
        String base64Image = 
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(product.getMainImage());
            product.setBase64Image(base64Image);
        }
        return "home";
    }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests() 
                .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/product").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/addProduct").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin() //start form based authentication
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout() //start logout behavior
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)// invalidate session on logout
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }

product.html condensed html
    <form method="post"
          role="form"
          th:action="@{/addProduct}"
          th:object="${product}"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
          <label for="mainImage">Main Image</label>
          <input type="file" id="mainImage" name="mainImage" accept="image/*">
    </div>
          <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
    </form>

application.properties
    spring.application.name=Ecom
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Ecom
    spring.datasource.username=****
    spring.datasource.password=****
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.Type = TRACE
    server.port=8042
    spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

Error Message
2024-04-14T08:34:12.821-05:00  WARN 48500 --- [Ecom] [nio-8042-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String com.example.Ecom.Controllers.ProductController.addItem(com.example.Ecom.Products.ProductDto,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile): [Field error in object 'product' on field 'mainImage': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@32278427]; codes [typeMismatch.product.mainImage,typeMismatch.mainImage,typeMismatch.[B,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [product.mainImage,mainImage]; arguments []; default message [mainImage]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'mainImage'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property 'mainImage[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile']] ]

I've been trying to fix this for 3 days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I made sure I used all the same code that worked from my previous program including the controller method, thymeleaf code, and project structure.
I tried private byte[] convertMultipartFileToBytes(MultipartFile file) throws IOException { return file.getBytes();}
I added the security config to permitAll.
Triple checked the database. The Dao, Dto, Service, ServiceImpl are the exact same as the talent manager.
I added spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
